# add condition in login of liferay

Tags: liferay

I work with liferay 5.2

I use Ldap for authentication, it works correctly,

Now I want to add a condition in my authentication,

I want to invoke another methode in login ,

this methode return **true or false** related to status of user connected,

this methode require the user id as parameter

This is a syntax of this methode :

```
boolean verifyStatusOfUser(String idUserConnected);
```

so in login  after verify the user in ldap I should invoke the previous methode with this syntax

```
verifyStatusOfUser(PortalUtil.getConnectedUserID(request)
                    .toUpperCase()));
```

and make a test  if the result is true the user can be connected and if the result is false the user can not connected

My methode verifyStatusOfUser  is in jar  so I should add this jar  in liferay

can sameone help me to change the login methode

Comment: Sorry, not enough time for a proper answer - check https://www.liferay.com/de/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/performing-a-custom-action, but note that 5.2 is quite old - my main suggestion (unless you're on EE) is to update to the latest version to be able to get updates

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I can't migrate to the latest version of liferay, because I have already an application with theme which is deployed in this version , so I should find a solution related to my liferay

Answer (score 0):

Ok, following up with some more suggestions on the comment given earlier:

Check a PostLoginAction. How to do them is documented in the Developer Guide https://www.liferay.com/de/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/performing-a-custom-action

In this you get access to the request, with it the current session. If somebody has logged in but you determine that they shouldn't, you can invalidate their session and - if you like - even redirect them to a page explaining the reasons.

An alternative is to hook into the AutoLogin functionality that Liferay has (this is similar to implementing a Single Sign On (SSO) system, but might be a bit harder.

It might be that the steps fro Liferay 5.2 differ slightly, but as far as I remember, a PostLogin action was already possible back then.

Repeating myself: Over time you really should consider an upgrade to the latest and supported versions. You're basically cut from updates - functionality and security - unless you're on the still supported Enterprise Edition.